# jQuery click() event does not work in Android Browser

Tags: android, jquery, android-browser

This code runs in Chrome, but not in Android Browser or Chrome for Android 18 (Android 4.2; CyanogenMod 10.1):

```
$(function(){
    $(".save").click(function(){
        alert('Saved');
    });
});
```

​
Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BCVdc/4/

Is there some jQuery/Android Browser incompatibility?

RESOLVED: error was unrelated to this code...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $(".save").click(function(){
        alert('Saved');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Above code should does the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Android browser to test in, but you may be having problems with a link not having a valid href attribute.

As an aside, this is also why some browsers won't apply the default anchor CSS to it as well. ie. the usual blue and underlined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(function(){
    $(".save").live('tap',function(event){
        alert('Saved1');
    });
$(".save").live('click',function(event){
        alert('Saved2');
    });
});
```

Please test it in your android and tell us which alert is shown.

Comment: `live` is deprecated. You should use `on` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue while trying to use the .click method on stock android browsers. Seems like substituting .click with `$('selector').on('click', cb);` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in mobile not working click, but can use onchange function.

```
$(function(){
  $('.save').on('change', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Saved');
  });
});
```